# Galaxy S8: screen height returning wrong value

Tags: android

This is how we're getting screen height:

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

The problem we're having is that with the Galaxy S8's hidden nav bar, the value returned is the height minus the nav bar size (even though the nav bar is hidden by the user).  How do we get the full usable height?

example:  screen height is 2220 pixels but the value returned is 2076

The answer needs to be able to work on Galaxy S8 with or without the nav bar hidden as well as other devices

thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this :

```
Point displaySize = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);
```

**Point** is a class **from android.graphics** package.

From docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)

> Gets the real size of the display without subtracting any window decor
>   or applying any compatibility scale factors.
>
> The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display.
>
> The real size may be smaller than the physical size of the screen when
>   the window manager is emulating a smaller display (using adb shell wm
>   size).

Edit :

I checked this code on LG G4 and it works fine :

```
//get the full height of device
      Point displaySize = new Point();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);

      Resources resources = getResources();
            int navBarId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");


          int fullHeight = displaySize.y;
//get nav bar size
          int navbarSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(navBarId);
          int availableSize = fullHeight;
//check is navbar is visible
          boolean navBarVisible = (getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility() &
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0;
          if(navBarVisible){
                    availableSize -= navbarSize;
                }
```

Also you can use this code :

```
view.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int i) {
                Log.d("Nav bar visible : ", String.valueOf((i & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)==0));
            }
        });
```

to check when nav bar is hiding.

Comment: trying it now.  Will this account for nav bar sizes on phones that don't hide it?

Comment: ok... so it returns the full height of the screen... but it does so whether the nav bar is hidden or not.  So when the nav bar is pinned visible, it's now returning too much

Comment: Ok, please check this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)
especially this method :
 __public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)__

Comment: "Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the status bar changes visibility. "  The issue is the nav bar, not the status bar.  this has nothing to do with setting full screen mode

Comment: unfortunately not.  Samsung really killed us with this.  It looks like it's fixed in the oreo beta but until the update rolls out system wide, this is going to remain an issue

Comment: Crap :/, sorry I didn't help :(

Comment: No worries.  Thank you so much for the help.  Sometimes getting around samsung is our biggest hurdle

Comment: The reason it didn't work, just so you know, is because the galaxy s8 has the ability to hide the navigation bar at all times with it becoming visible on a swipe up.  This is enabled by the user in the phone settings.  The phone, however, returns available height as if the nav bar was there, regardless if it's hidden or not.  It's a real pain

Comment: @Ambi unfortunately not. The only positive is that, based on the S8 Beta program, this appears to be fixed so it should only be a problem until the update rolls out to every s8 device

Comment: @Ambi there is a flag in manifest you can set so your app won't accept the 2:1 aspect ratio and force the navigation bar to show. I'm on mobile so can't post a link but it's easily searchable. That's what I ended up doing. Once the update gets pushed to all devices, I'll do another update with that flag removed

Comment: @Psest328 Thanks for the advice.
I managed to workaround by getting the height of android.R.id.content, which will return the correct height value. Of course, you need to do this after layout is drawn, so it might not be the best depending on your use case.

Comment: I saw that but because our codebase is so terrible (I'm refactoring my predecessor's mistakes on that), it actually causes a crash that I can't identify. I was going to look into it more but since I discovered that the issue is fixed in next release, I abandoned the task

Comment: @Psest328 I still this issue on S8. The screen height is less than window height when nav bar is hidden. Do you know if Samsung fixed this at all? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Aadithya Good News:  The value is fixed on the Galaxy S8 Oreo Update!  Bad News:  If the user is still on Nougat, there is no 'fix'. You have to try one of the workarounds.  2nd Good News: The oreo update for the S8s has gone out worldwide so the user being on nougat shouldn't really be a thing anymore

Comment: @Psest328 Good to know. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Aadithya i have s8 plus with oreo but still i am  getting wrong value of height(navigationbar height is not included)

Comment: @Psest328 Are you sure it's been fixed? I still get the wrong value like the above comment says

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve this with the decorview:

```
//Get the correct screen size even if the device has a hideable navigation bar (e.g. the Samsung Galaxy S8)
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); //if you use this in a fragment, use getActivity before getWindow()
Rect r = new Rect();
decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
int screenHeight = r.bottom; // =2220 on S8 with hidden NavBar and =2076 with enabled NavBar
int screenWidth = r.right; // =1080 on S8
```